# How can I post new comment with Graph API into Social Comments Box?( http)

Tags: http, facebook-graph-api, graph, access-token, facebook-comments

I want to comment on post with graph api

but dont work graph api

https://graph.facebook.com/id/comments?access_token=&message= test

Comment: Do you want to create a comment, add a graph to it and post it manually, or do it through code? Also, please post whatever code you have tried!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't know how to use the Facebook Graph API, or HTTP, but I googled for how to post comments, and found [this in the API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/comments#publish):

> ### Publishing
>
> You can publish new comments to any object as below:
>
> ```
> POST /v2.2/{object-id}/comments HTTP/1.1
> Host: graph.facebook.com
>
> message=This+is+a+test+comment
> ```
>
> #### Permissions
>
> - A user access token with `publish_actions` permission can be used to publish new comments.
> - The same user must also be able to comment on the object.
> - The `can_comment` field on individual [comment objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/comment/) indicates whether it is possible to reply to that comment by
>     publishing another.

You might be able to use this, but change the `message` to whatever specifies your graph.

However, keep in mind that this might not work, because I have no experience with the Facebook Graph API. I found this in the documentation.